# Thread Executor: running multiple process and pool wait for 30 minutes before starts next process

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, java.util.concurrent, threadpoolexecutor

Currently I am working to implement multiprocessing using `ThreadPoolExecutor` API. Below is the requirement to process

1. Defined no. of java process to run at a time using ThreadPool using `ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);`
2. And i am submitting all actual process of runnable jar process to pool

   ```
   for(int i=1; i<50; i++) {
     RunnableTask r=new RunnableTask();
     executor.submit(r);
   }
   ```

and actual RunnableTask is follows

```
public class RunnableTask implements Runnable{
  public void run(){
  Process p=Runtime.exec("java -jar D:\ProcessIntiate.jar");
}
```

Now when pool is started only 3 process will starts parallel.

I want to run only 3 process at a time and after completion of 3 process my pool has to be wait for 30 minutes and needs to start next 3 processes. And notification has to be required to pool when all 3 process is completed.

Is there any way using ThreadExcutorFramwork?

Comment: Why do you want to run java code in another process in the first place? You could as well use a distinct class loader and keep everything in the JVM that is already running? Just saying ..

Comment: @GhostCat, thanks for reply. But the actual business logic is resides in this jar ProcessIntiate.jar (assigning some minimum and maximum memory to that while running)  (java -jar -xms512m -xmx2048m D:\ProcessIntiate.jar). This is long running process and will consume more memory for that. this is process has to be monitor by pool until to complete

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution: simply add a 30 minute wait to your Runnable code.

Or better: give the runable a parameter that controls how long it waits.
For the first 47 processes, you give 30 minutes; and then 0.

Alternatively simply don't submit 50 tasks. 
Instead: use an outer thread that pushes 3 tasks and then waits/sleeps until those 3 are done. Then wait 30 minutes and push another 3.

Comment: I cant give 30 min to single Runnable and pool has to wait after completion of 3 proceses. once 3 process are completed..wait for 30 min ...next 3 process has to be executed by pool and so on

the actual business logic is resides in this jar ProcessIntiate.jar (assigning some minimum and maximum memory to that while running) (java -jar -xms512m -xmx2048m D:\ProcessIntiate.jar). This is long running process and will consume more memory for that. this is process has to be monitor by pool until to complete.

Comment: @Rajasekhar_b_1989 Some feedback would be welcome. I gave you two ways to go; but neither upvote, nor accept; and not even a comment "I need some more help because". Long story short: other people spent their time to help you; so consider the one minute it takes to give some sort of feedback to them!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly submitting the request to thread pool, store it in a collection.

Use a ScheduledExecutorService with size 1 to schedule a task which will run after specified interval (say 30 mins in your case).

It will take task from the collection in batch and will submit it to another pool where it is actually programmed to process the submitted task.

```
class CustomScheduledExecutor  {
ScheduledExecutorService scheduleExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

Queue<Runnable> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Runnable>();

public CustomScheduledExecutor(){
    scheduleExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                Runnable poll = queue.poll(); // Do the handling for queue size
                executorService.submit(poll);
            }
        }
    }, 1000, 30, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}

public void submitTask(Runnable runnable){
    queue.offer(runnable);
}

}
```

submit also returns future instances so you have a control on the submitted task and can manipulate as per need.